Phenol reaction with nitration mixture
When phenol is reacted with nitration mixture my teacher said that picric acid as minor product and a major oxidation product. Is that oxidation product benzoquinone or anything else?

Yes, that's correct. Benzoquinone is one of the byproducts of
nitration reaction and it occurs from oxidation.

During the preparation of nitrophenols, by-products of oxidation, in particular benzoquinone derivatives and derivatives of high molecular mass originating from the condensation of several aromatic molecules, are frequently observed, and this necessitates carrying out awkward purification operations.
[...]
Although it leads to a good yield of nitrophenol derivative, this variant of the process yields a nitrophenol derivative containing impurities which are the by-products of the reaction. Among these impurities are benzoquinone derivatives which originate from the oxidation of the phenol derivative. These color the nitrophenol derivative.

Source: IE58428B1 - Process for nitration of phenol derivatives

Only *derivatives" seem to be mentioned...

@Mithoron That could be because oxidation does not"have to" stop at benzoquinone. The carbon-carbon double bonds may well react further.

@OscarLanzi My point is you get some variable, colored gunk, which might get some slight amount of actual C4H4O2, or picric acid. Mostly its oxidatively coupled nitrooligomer stuff.

Last night benzoquinone was C6H4O2, but overall yeah.
